# Revert flagged comment

Tags: feature-request

I don't think that there is a current way to reverse a flagged comment, however one can reverse upvotes, downvotes, edits, upvoted comments and close requests.
Is it possible to also include reverts of a comment flag?

The reason I think this would be good would be to not bug the admins who clean up the comments in case one makes a mistake.

Personally I try to flag as much obsolete and chatty comments that I can but I realize that I sometimes makes mistakes in the line of *"ups, this comment actually **do** have value, even though half of it is refers to something obsolete."*.

My suggestion in that case would be to click the red flag in order to reverse it again, similar to how reverse upvoted comments works. As well, if you once revert the flag it cannot be flagged again.